# vtkImageAppend doesn't seem to be producing valid vtkImageData

Tags: python, vtk, medical-imaging

I have a few DICOM stacks for different bones in a hand and I want to 3-D render the entire hand.  So far I can only get a single bone to render.

I am using the python vtk and vtkplotter libraries.

So far I've tried creating a vtkImageData object for each DICOM image and feed them all into the vtkImageAppend object using vtkImageAppend.AddInputData().

The code is the function I'm using to append all the images, which are passed to the function as a list called vtkList.

```
def CombineVTKs(vtkList):
    "Returns a Single VTKImageData given a list of individual ones"
    a = vtk.vtkImageAppend()
    a.SetAppendAxis(2)
    for l in vtkList:
        a.AddInputData(l)
    return a.GetOutput()
```

The output of the CombineVTKs() function is a '(vtkCommonDataModelPython.vtkImageData)' object, but when I try to create a vtkplotter.Volume() object and show it, everything breaks and makes me very sad.  Here's the code and following error(s):

```
a = CombineVTKs(myVtkList)
vol = vtkplotter.Volume(a)
vtkplotter.show(vol, bg='white')
```

The errors produced are:

```
ERROR: In C:\VPP\standalone-build\VTK- 
source\Rendering\Volume\vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper.cxx, line 336
vtkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper (000002B3516FA9C0): No scalars named "" 
or with id -1 found on input.

ERROR: In C:\VPP\standalone-build\VTK- 
source\Rendering\Volume\vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper.cxx, line 336
vtkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper (000002B3516FA9C0): No scalars named "" 
or with id -1 found on input.
```

Has anyone used vtk &&/|| vtkplotter to do something similar or does anyone have a suggestion for another way to complete this?

Comment: have you managed to solve this? or still need help?

Comment: running an a.Update() before GetOutput() ? A few examples also require you to specify the index you are appending a.SetInput(sliceIndex, l) ? Can you sendsome data and we can look to build a MWE